# What is the current status of Penrose Conformal Cyclic Cosmology?

Tags: general-relativity

A [brief summary from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology)

> Penrose's basic construction is to connect a countable sequence of
>   open Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker metric (FLRW) spacetimes,
>   each representing a big bang followed by an infinite future expansion.
>   Penrose noticed that the past conformal boundary of one copy of FLRW
>   spacetime can be "attached" to the future conformal boundary of
>   another, after an appropriate conformal rescaling.

Furthermore, there does seem to be some experimental evidence. Specifically:

> In 2010, Penrose and Vahe Gurzadyan published a preprint of a paper
>   claiming that observations of the cosmic microwave background made by
>   the Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe and the BOOMERanG experiment
>   showed concentric anomalies which were consistent with the CCC
>   hypothesis

Comment: Completely hypothetical, although I have to give it two thumbs up. I like the basic idea.

Comment: Regarding the close vote as *primarily opinion-based*: I do not see what about asking about the current status of a theory established in peer-reviewed articles constitutes a "primarily opinion-based" question. Sure, there are possible opinion-based answers, but there's also the obvious non-opinion-based one: The answer surveying the status of emprical confirmation as well as recent theoretical developments in this direction.

Comment: @CuriousOne Surprised at the thumbs up - I thought you hated multiverse theories

Comment: But it's not a multiverse theory. @ACuriousMind: A theoretical model for the long term future of the universe (and a past that is shrouded by an event horizon, as far as we can tell), can never be anything else than opinion. I do admit that I like it, that I might even be evangelizing among layman for the advantages of something like this model, but I will never pretend that I have any hopes of bringing it down from the level of an opinion to even the level of a working scientific theory for the present era within my lifetime. The younger ones among us may be more optimistic...

Comment: @CuriousOne Cyclic universe models are multiverse models as they cycle through all possible states. Also, if you read the text, "(and a past that is shrouded by an event horizon, as far as we can tell), can never be anything else than opinion." is not true and they offer evidence

Comment: There is no such thing as "every possible state" in physics, and certainly not in cosmology with an ever expanding phase space. That kind of thought only arises from faulty pre-20th century math. An ever expanding universe is a pretty natural single universe model, albeit it one with a fractal effective potential. Evidence are measurements. There are no measurements from before 300,000 years after the big bang. That, and nucleosynthesis ratios, are the last direct signals we have.  Do we really have to discuss the difference between theory and evidence, again?

Comment: @CuriousOne So what of the evidence that Penrose claims exists? His theory makes predictions that he claims have been verified

Comment: See my first comment... I would put it at "completely hypothetical", but likable.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's not what I asked. Have you seen the evidence he puts forward?

Comment: Consistency is no more evidence that a model is correct than not failing school is evidence for intellectual performance. You can make these kinds of models consistent with any cosmological data you like, just like you can make epicycles consistent with short term observational data.

Comment: @CuriousOne Answer the question please. Have you seen the evidence he puts forward?

Comment: Yes, and I don't consider that evidence. It's a theoretician playing data analyst on an experiment that he has no clue about. Even if the data would agree with the prediction, you would probably be looking at half a century of modeling to rule out any other possible cause. Don't get your hopes up... there will be ten feet of fresh bones on top of your and mine and Penrose's graves before the dust will settle on this. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne: if you aren't allowing theorists to posit theories that can later be checked for consistency, you really don't want physics to exist.  Similar criticisms of General Relativity itself were commonplace in 1916.  Even if the base ontology of a model can't be directly checked, that doesn't mean that there aren't other parts of it that can be, and if a theory like that checks out, that doesn't mean that a more parsimonious model that is consistent with the first one can be worked out.  This weird positivism contradicts how most theoretical physics has worked, successfully.

Comment: Like, even Newton was railed against by Cartesians for having gravity act by an unseeable force field, rather than a substance, and how could he propose something like that without knowing what was going on and not seeing the unseen mechanism involved.

Comment: Although it is still a very preliminary and hypothetical proposal, I have the impression that it is gaining popularity. The number number of papers on the subject is increasing: 1090 (2005-10), 1550 (2011-2015), 1890 (2016-2020), 
1040 (2021-).